# I'm unable to find a result in my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm not getting any result in my div

Here is my jquery

```
$('#btnsearchres').click(function(){
                var $server;
                var content;
                $server = 'http://localhost/XDK/';
   $.getJSON("http://localhost/XDK/timeline.php",function(data){

      $.each(data.recipes, function(i,post){
        content = '<p>' + post.i_name + '</p>';
        content += '<p>' + post.i_recipe + '</p>';
        content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+post.image_thumb+'"/>';
        content += '<br/>';

      });
       $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
    });
```

My JSON

```
{
    "i_id": "1",
    "i_name": "Biryani",
    "i_category": "Pakistani",
    "i_Uploader_Name": "Nabeel",
    "i_recipe": "2 cups Basmati- RIce \r\n3\/4kg Chicken pieces \r\nOnion 3 large, slIced \r\n1 cup Yoghurt \r\n1 tsp Ginger paste \r\n1\/2 tsp Garlic paste \r\n1 tsp Green chilli paste \r\n1\/2 cup Tomato puree \r\n2 tsp Red Chilli powder \r\n1 tsp Turmeric powder \r\n1 tsp Cumin powder (roasted) \r\n1\/2 tsp Cardamom powder \r\n2 tsp Garam masala powder \r\n1\/2 cup Milk \r\nA pinch Saffron \r\n1 tsp Coriander powder \r\nGreen Coriander leaves 2 tbsp, chopped \r\nWater 3 1\/2 cups \r\n7 tbsp Oil \r\nSalt as required\r\n\r\nMETHOD :\r\n1. Make a mixture with t",
    "i_tags": "",
    "i_ingredients": "Chicken Rice Ginger Garlic Garam-masala Green-chilli-paste Turmeric-powder Safron",
    "i_dateofadd": "2016-01-24",
    "i_rate": "0",
    "image_name": "Biryani-main1.jpg",
    "image_path": "images\/Biryani-main1.jpg",
    "image_thumb": "thumb\/Biryani-main1.jpg"
}
```

and I have a div called recipes in my html

```
 <input id="btnsearchres" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search"/>
            <input id="btnaddrec" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Add Recipe"/>
  </div>
        <div id="recipes">
  </div>
```

i couldnt get any of the results

I want my result to be seen on html file when my btnsearch button is pressed but it is not showing a thing

Comment: you can put your code and html here..

Comment: Instead of using `post.i_name`, have you tried it like `post['i_name']`??

Comment: And also have you checked your console.log for any errors?

Comment: Line Problem Code snippet
117 ['i_name'] is better written in dot notation. (W069) content = '<p>' + post['i_name'] + '</p>';
118 ['i_recipe'] is better written in dot notation. (W069) content += '<p>' + post['i_recipe'] + '</p>';
119 ['image_thumb'] is better written in dot notation. (W069) content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+post['image_thumb']+'"/>';

Comment: Can you post how the json data is coming up?

Comment: the errors have just been posted above

Comment: posted mr.dvenkatsagar

Comment: Should I assume according to @Sabik solution the recipes are in that format??

Comment: I'm using php echo json_encode method 
what should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the code should work and I assume the JSON code should be like this:

```
{
  "recipes" : [
     {
       "i_id": "1",
       "i_name": "Biryani",
       "i_category": "Pakistani",
       "i_Uploader_Name": "Nabeel",
       "i_recipe": "2 cups Basmati- RIce \r\n3\/4kg Chicken pieces \r\nOnion 3 large, slIced \r\n1 cup Yoghurt \r\n1 tsp Ginger paste \r\n1\/2 tsp Garlic paste \r\n1 tsp Green chilli paste \r\n1\/2 cup Tomato puree \r\n2 tsp Red Chilli powder \r\n1 tsp Turmeric powder \r\n1 tsp Cumin powder (roasted) \r\n1\/2 tsp Cardamom powder \r\n2 tsp Garam masala powder \r\n1\/2 cup Milk \r\nA pinch Saffron \r\n1 tsp Coriander powder \r\nGreen Coriander leaves 2 tbsp, chopped \r\nWater 3 1\/2 cups \r\n7 tbsp Oil \r\nSalt as required\r\n\r\nMETHOD :\r\n1. Make a mixture with t",
       "i_tags": "",
       "i_ingredients": "Chicken Rice Ginger Garlic Garam-masala Green-chilli-paste Turmeric-powder Safron",
       "i_dateofadd": "2016-01-24",
       "i_rate": "0",
       "image_name": "Biryani-main1.jpg",
       "image_path": "images\/Biryani-main1.jpg",
       "image_thumb": "thumb\/Biryani-main1.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if the data that is returned is a single object in a array, in the format the you have given in the question, then you might want to change the `data.recipes` to `data` and check if it works.

Update:

According your comment on what the timeline.php does, I think it returns only one result. so you might want to change the javascript to something like this:

```
$('#btnsearchres').click(function(){
                var $server;
                var content;
                $server = 'http://localhost/XDK/';
   $.getJSON("http://localhost/XDK/timeline.php",function(data){
        content = '<p>' + data.i_name + '</p>';
        content += '<p>' + data.i_recipe + '</p>';
        content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+data.image_thumb+'"/>';
        content += '<br/>';
        $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
    });
});
```

Comment: How can i do that ?
i just used json_encode method in timeline.php

Comment: Show me the contents of timeline.php?

Comment: Or actually better than that, just change the `data.recipes` to `data` and check if it works.

Comment: $SQL = "SELECT * FROM items";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($SQL, $serve);  
    $row =mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result);
    echo json_encode($row);

Comment: I think this will return only one result.... right?? If so, you might want to remove the `$.each()` and only keep the content and change the `post` to `data`

Comment: what if i need more then one result?
Can you update post with multiple

Comment: One final suggestion, you might want to change your timeline.php with a better logic, you code is only returning 1 result, but I think you intend to return as many result there are, you might want to change that. There are implementations available online. I cannot answer it because, i think it would be off-topic for this post. If this helps, kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have the append the wrong way around, instead of:

```
   $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
    $('#recipes').append(content);
```

In your for loop:

```
    $.each(data.recipes, function(i,post){
        content = '<p>' + post.i_name + '</p>';
        content += '<p>' + post.i_recipe + '</p>';
        content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+post.image_thumb+'"/>';
        content += '<br/>';
    });
    $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
```

You re-initialise the content on each iteration, shouldn't you then move the append statement as the last line inside the loop?

```
    $.each(data.recipes, function(i,post){
        content = '<p>' + post.i_name + '</p>';
        content += '<p>' + post.i_recipe + '</p>';
        content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+post.image_thumb+'"/>';
        content += '<br/>';
        $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
    });
```

I think you are getting an error in the loop itself, you are passing 'i' as the first parameter, but you only reference I as part of the parameter name.  This will not work as you think, I will be taken as part of the variable name not replaced with the value of 'i', it isn't a macro.  If this is your intention then use:

```
    post[i].i_name
```

Also I would suggest using an alternative name other than post, something like aryRecipes, where the prefix ary tells everyone that the variable is an array.  Try using some console.dir() statements in the loop to verify the values.

e.g:

```
    $.each(data.recipes, function(i,post){
        console.log("i :" + i + ", post:");
        console.dir(post);
        content = '<p>' + post.i_name + '</p>';
        content += '<p>' + post.i_recipe + '</p>';
        content += '<img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+post.image_thumb+'"/>';
        content += '<br/>';
        $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
    });
```

Comment: Can you post an update of the source as there are errors in the source...or can you confirm that the posted source is what you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see array in your received json. In your code data.resipes wtah is recipes? If i understand your code correct your json must be like

```
{"recipes" : [{recipe 1}, {recipe 2}]}
```

Comment: {"i_id":"1","i_name":"Biryani","i_category":"Pakistani","i_Uploader_Name":"Nabeel","i_recipe":"a mixture with t","i_tags":"","i_ingredients":"Chicken Rice Ginger Garlic Garam-masala Green-chilli-paste Turmeric-powder Safron","i_dateofadd":"2016-01-24","i_rate":"0","image_name":"Biryani-main1.jpg","image_path":"images\/Biryani-main1.jpg","image_thumb":"thumb\/Biryani-main1.jpg"}